# How to send SQLite database using email?

Tags: ios, sqlite, email

I'm developing iPhone application (running on iOS 7.0+) that uses SQLite database. The problem is facing me when I'm trying to send the database by email, it either does not respond when I use the following code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *cm=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
cm.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[cm setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"EMAIL Address here",nil]];
[cm setSubject:@""];
[cm setMessageBody:@"Mensage" isHTML:YES];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_dbname" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

[cm addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:path];

[self presentViewController:cm animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

or sends the email when I update the attachment line to:

```
[cm addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:@"my_dbname.sqlite"];
```

Also, the view does not go off when I press "Cancel" button or "Send" button.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: To dismiss the composer you need to implement the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` method and call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on the controller.

Comment: The file name is the name used by the email, unrelated to where it is on disk. I'll hazard a guess that full file paths are improperly supported by different email clients or possibly not part of the spec at all. Is there a reason why the `my_dbname.sqlite` solution isn't acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Is your sqlite database open when attempting to attach the file?    If the database is open, maybe there is a lock on the database file??

Implementing the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate as rmaddy suggested will fix the issue of dismissing the controller.

How big in size is the sqlite database?    Maybe everything is fine with the code, and you just have a really large file :-)